# Vary particle hair settings within same system?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

Is it possible to have a particle hair system that has multiple different settings combinations in it? For example, have different settings for hair thickness, or child shape and clump?

Alternatively, if you have multiple particle hair systems with different settings, can you get their dynamics to interact together as if they were the same system?

Comment: You can drive it with a texture

Comment: This question is one of the top hits for "particle hair" can someone expand on VRM's "You can drive it with a texture" comment?